# Property 'id' is missing in type {`id`} using GraphQL and Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, graphql

I am new to coding and Typescript in general so pardon my lack of knowledge. I am trying to get my application to talk  to my api, but I get the following error because of my primary id key having a "?" as follows:

```
export interface PartMaster {
    id?: number;
 }
```

When I remove the "?" I get a different error and when I keep it I also get a different error. Am I missing something in GraphQL? I am mostly front end developer, and my coworker has done all of the GraphQL management, but I need to figure this out on my own today so any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code it does not like when I have the "?" in id:

```
computed: {
    part(): PartMaster {
      return {
        partNumber: this.partNumber,
        
      }
    }
  },
```

The error reads property 'id' missing in type partNumber

This is the error when I include the "?":

```
editRow(partMaster.id)
editRow(part.id)
```

It underlines the partmaster.id and the part.id with the following error:

Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: Do not include the question mark unless for some reason the id might not be there. Otherwise if it will be there you can either use the bang operator ! to assert that value will not be undefined or you write a null guard before the call the edit row. Like if (value) { editRow(..) } that way the code doesn’t try to execute if the value isn’t there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question really needs more details, including the sections where  the `editRow` function is defined and where your GraphQL query is called, and the text of the error when `id` is not marked as optional. However, I don't yet have enough reputation to comment so will address this in an answer instead.

With the information given, here is what I can guess:

- The last error messages that you give (`Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.`) are likely because `editRow` expects an argument of type `number`. By marking`id` as optional, you indicate that it may sometimes be `undefined`. Either don't mark it as optional, or make `editRow` accept `number | undefined` and handle the `undefined` case in code.
- In the case where you remove the "?" from id, what I would check first is that your GraphQL query does in fact request the `id` field. The point of GraphQL is to only request what you need so it is possible that your coworker has not added this field to the request. If it's not that, I wouldn't be able to help without the extra details mentioned above.